# Android MediaRecorder Multiple Files

Tags: android, video, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I am using a MediaRecorder to record video from the camera save it as .mp4 to the SDCard, which works flawlessly.  I would like to limit the length of the .mp4 files to 10 seconds each and then automatically create a new file (ie:  If a user records 30 seconds I would like to create three files, segment1.mp4 (0:00-0:10), segment2.mp4 (0:10-0:20), and segment3.mp4 (0:20-0:30)).

Here is where I set up the recorder and the output.  What should I be doing to make this happen while recording?

```
private boolean prepareVideoRecorder() {

        this.mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        this.mCamera.stopPreview();
        this.mCamera.unlock();
        this.mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
        this.mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        this.mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        this.mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
        this.mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(this.VIDEO_CHUNK_LENGTH_MS);  //10,000 ms
        if (getAndroidSDKVersion() >= 8) {
            this.mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
        } else {
            this.mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            this.mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
            this.mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
        }
        this.mVideoFileName = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString(); // Returns a proper file name
        this.mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mVideoFileName);
        this.mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());

        try {
            this.mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            this.releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            this.releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Given latency in getting `MediaRecorder` to start recording, I would expect that you will have significant gaps between the chunks.

Comment: Have you Managed to Solve This problem ?

Comment: Maybe, you can try to record a complete file, then splits the file use ffmpeg.